# Why are stalks of sheaves defined as colimits?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal F$ be a sheaf on a topological space $X$, i.e. a functor $\mathcal F: \mathbf{Ouv}(X)\to R$ with some algebraic category $R$, for example rings. The functor $\mathcal F$ assigns an algebraic structure to each open set of $X$.

For any point $x$ we get a set of neighbourhoods $\{U_i\}$ ($x\in U_i$ for all $i\in I$), which forms a directed system by inclusion: we have a "direction" $U_i \to U_j$ iff $U_i\subset U_j$.

As I understand it, the concept of a stalk $\mathcal F_x$ of $x\in X$ tries to capture the sheaf's local behavior around a point $x\in X$. To realize this, I would expect to have inclusions $\mathcal F_x\subset U_i$ for each $i\in I$. The stalk $\mathcal F_x$ should be something very small around $x$.

Now, the stalk $\mathcal F_x$ of $x$ [is defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#Stalks_of_a_sheaf) as the **direct limit** of the directed system $\{U_i\}$, [which is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit#Direct_limit_over_a_direct_system_in_a_category) the **colimit** of the directed system as a functor. This means that instead of the inclusions $\mathcal F_x\subset U_i$, we have arrows (directions, i.e. inclusions) $U_i\to\mathcal F_x$, i.e. $U_i\subset\mathcal F_x$.

I think that cannot be correct. I really expect an inclusion $\mathcal F_x\subset U_i$, and not the other way round.

What did I understand wrong? Are the two linked Wiki pages correct?

Comment: 1) You meant to write “$\mathcal F U_i$” instead of “$U_i$” in “$\mathcal F_x ⊂ U_i$”, “$U_i → \mathcal F_x$” and “$U_i ⊂ \mathcal F_x$”, right? 2) Note that in general the map $\mathcal F U_i → \mathcal F_x$ is *not* an inclusion, i.e. not injective, very seldomly so in fact. 3) Sheaves abstractly capture the notion of *functions on a space*, if $U_i ⊂ U_j$ the map $\mathcal FU_j → \mathcal FU_i$ is an abstraction of the restriction map “$f  ↦ f|_{U_i}$”. I’m pretty certain, though, that someone else will soon explain that a whole lot better than I can, with historic notes and motivation etc.

Comment: @k.stm I think your first point nails it already. A sheaf is a *contravariant* functor $\mathcal F:X\to R$, so the inclusion arrows $U_i\to U_j$ are reversed to $\mathcal F(U_j)\to \mathcal F(U_i)$. I think this is the reversion I was looking for. The colimit of the directed system $\{\mathcal FU_i\}$ has arrows $\mathcal FU_i\to \mathcal F_x$, but these correspond to inclusions as I expected them (intuitively, it's ${\mathcal F_x}^{-1}\to U_i$).